# Not able to run Oozie job from Hue (Apache Ambari Configured and link to Hue)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie, hue, bigdata

I have installed `Apache Ambari` and installed `oozie` service and configured with `hue` service. when I run `oozie` job (pig script) but 33% only job run and stuck. I got following log from `oozie`.

```
2017-06-02 10:47:28,834  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[c6401.ambari.apache.org] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My Workflow] JOB[0000013-170602085528204-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000013-170602085528204-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000013-170602085528204-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2017-06-02 10:47:28,835  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[c6401.ambari.apache.org] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My Workflow] JOB[0000013-170602085528204-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000013-170602085528204-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000013-170602085528204-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2017-06-02 10:47:28,835  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[c6401.ambari.apache.org] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My Workflow] JOB[0000013-170602085528204-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000013-170602085528204-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000013-170602085528204-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2017-06-02 10:47:28,878  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[c6401.ambari.apache.org] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000013-170602085528204-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000013-170602085528204-oozie-oozi-W
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: After Oozie has submitted the Pig action to YARN, it does not care about what is really happening; it just waits for a final status (either FINISHED, KILLED or FAILED). You must open the YARN UI to get more details...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Hi Thanks for Answser but defualt porrt for job tracker set 8032 but in server it is running on 8050 so I have changed it and now it is working but I am again facing some another issue if you can give me answer please check below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343143/not-able-to-export-hbase-table-into-csv-file-using-hue-pig-script

Comment: If you solved the issue yourself, then either delete your question ("was not a real issue, no interest to leave it in SO") or mark it as "Solved" somehow.

Comment: @Samson: we don't mark questions as "solved" here in the title. Instead we encourage self-answers, and then clicking the tick/check mark, to accept it.