# Not able to export Hbase table into CSV file using HUE Pig Script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie, hue, ambari

I have installed `Apache Amabari` and configured the `Hue`. I want to export `hbase` table data into `csv` file using `pig` script but I am getting following error.

2017-06-03 10:27:45,518 [ATS Logger 0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl  - Exception caught by TimelineClientConnectionRetry, will try 30 more time(s).
Message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2017-06-03 10:27:45,703 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation  - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2017-06-03 10:27:45,709 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 101: file '/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.2.0-cdh5.11.0.jar' does not exist.
2017-06-03 10:27:45,899 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main  - Pig script completed in 4 seconds and 532 milliseconds (4532 ms)

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exit code [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Etk1.png)

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

[image]

[image]

Please help me and where I am doing wrong.

Let me know your concerns.

Comment: The error message is very explicit: Oozie submits the Pig action to YARN, then YARN starts Pig an a worker node... but the HBase client JARs are not installed on the worker nodes (or installed in a different location). So your `REGISTER` commands fail miserably.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Could you explain me in details as I have install Hbase on all cluster.